# Is there any db2 equivalent to mssql openrowset or opendatasource

Tags: sql-server, db2

Is there any db2 equivalent to mssql openrowset or opendatasource? also, is it possible to use different architectures? (db2 32bit select to sql server 64bit)

Comment: Yes DB2 does this via a feature called Federation.  There are a number of steps, you have to define the user mapping and then the actual tables / queries you want to federate.  Then it works like magic and the remote table looks like a local table. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.found.conn.fw.db2.doc/topics/tlsdb210.html

Comment: TLDR: `CREATE NICKNAME`